# How to control the timeout in Domino NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there any way to set the connect timeout and/or read timeout of the NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR method?  I could not find any documentation that covers this.  I found that the timeout is about 100 seconds on a Windows machine and around 10 minutes on a Linux Machine, I would like to set it to a shorter time, say 30 seconds.

```
String ior = NotesFactory.getIOR(dominoServer, args);
Session session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(ior, args, username, password);
```

The stacktrace on a windows machine

```
NotesException: Could not open Notes session
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.initSession(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionUP(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(Unknown Source)
    at DominoUtils.connect4(DominoUtils.java:1475)
    at DominoUtilsTest.testConnect4(DominoUtilsTest.java:347)
...
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out Host: 192.168.208.131 Port: 60148  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.ConnectionTable.get(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.ConnectionTable.get(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Generic.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Generic.locate(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invokePreamble(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.corba._IObjectServerStub.createSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Connection.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether we are able to set the *timeout* property at runtime, but you might have some control of it at *Server* document, *Internet Protocols / DIIO* tab. 
[image]